# Docker container corrupted

Tags: docker, docker-compose

by mistake i remove some files from overlay folder in /var/lib due to size increases.
now i am not able to run docker-compose build, up or even not able to login to container.
i am getting below error.

docker-compose -f docker-compose-jenkins.yaml up

```
ERROR: stat /var/lib/docker/overlay2/ef7f3084c8db586b88d5f825114c144effed007be79da415629838ad77363177: 
no such file or directory

docker exec -it 59dcdc4e2fba bas
Error response from daemon: readlink /var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/W5MHBAJA75EJKO7OPSB6TQ6DXU: no such file or directory

docker-compose ps
ERROR:
        Can't find a suitable configuration file in this directory or any
        parent. Are you in the right directory?

        Supported filenames: docker-compose.yml, docker-compose.yaml
even jenkins jobs are also failing.
```

Comment: The easy answer is to stop Docker, delete the entire `/var/lib/docker` directory, and restart the daemon.  You'll lose all of Docker's current state, but (except for named volumes) all of this should be able to be recreated by re-pulling/building images and then running new containers.

Comment: everything gone. i have to start everything from scratch